# Create a confirmation message overlay within form wrap

Tags: jquery, forms, overlay, confirmation

I need a confirmation message to appear after submission. I don't want pop ups. I don't want to change page. Instead, I would like the `<div> #input_form` to be covered with an overlay with html message inside. I hope this makes sense.

How would I do this with jQuery?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a simplified version of my code. I already have validation in place:

```
<form id="form_volunteer" name="form_volunteer">
  <div id="input_form">
     <input class="req-string" name="first_name" type="text" value="">
     <input name="company_name" type="text" value="">
     <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="form_vol" >
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

html

```
<form id="form_volunteer" name="form_volunteer">
  <div id="input_form">
     <div id="confirm"></div>
     <div id="myform">
     <input class="req-string" name="first_name" type="text" value="">
     <input name="company_name" type="text" value="">
     <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="form_vol" >
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

css

```
    #confirm,#myform{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:#eee;}

    #confirm{
    z-index:0;}
```

---

jquery

```
    $('#form_volunteer .submit').click(function(){
       $('#confirm').css('z-index','2');
    });
```

in jquery you cna also use the submit function and use preventdefault...

Comment: I would use `display:none;` on the `#confirm` and `fadeIn()` on confirmation.